# Gitlab CI don't test if there are no changes to the code (pytest-testmon)

Tags: gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci

I want to perform tests using gitlab CI using pytest-testmon. Unfortunately it seems that the generated file `.testmondata` is not saved in the gitlab-runner instances, so that no recollection of what was tested is saved.

Is there a way of saving this .testmondata and using it (for every different branch at test) in order to avoid repeating tests of unchanged code when code is pushed to those branches?

Comment: About question of "saving artifacts through jobs in the same pipeline": it describes here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html. If you will have a trouble with this - i can explain it as an answer. pytest-testmon is a very interesting instrument, thank you for a question, i join this and will try to resolve it. By the way the question was asked at over a month ago, @vladimir-vargas have you already found the solution?

Comment: @gore I have not found the solution. Artifacts look interesting, but they expire. I do not see (because of my ignorance) how they can be used for the task I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files generated during your job to Gitlab so you can view them later by downloading them, viewing on a Merge Request, or using them in other jobs by using the `artifacts` keyword. Here's a simple example:

```
tests:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - ./run_tests.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .testmondata
    name: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME_tests_testmondata"
    expose_as: 'Tests Results'
    expire_in: 3 months
```

In this example, after your `script` section (and `before_script` or `after_script` if present) runs, gitlab-runner will look for a file/directory that matches the entries in the `paths` array. If none are found, it will throw an error.

The runner will then upload the artifacts to Gitlab using the name in the `name` field. It's good practice to use some of the predefined variables that Gitlab CI provides so you can easily identify which pipeline and job an artifact came from, if necessary. In this example the name has the branch or tag name, and then `_tests_testmondata`.

The next attribute, `expose_as` lets you put a link on a Merge Request for this branch to display the artifacts. Without `expose_as`, you'll have to open the Pipeline and Job to view the artifacts.

Next, `expire_in` lets you define when the artifacts from this job should expire. If you don't set this attribute, the artifacts will expire based on the Gitlab server's setting, which by default is 30 days. You can supply a number of seconds as an int (`3600`, or one hour), `never` (to never expire), or many other human-readable formats like `3 years 8 months 28 days` or `46 months`.

You can view all the available predefined variables here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html, and you can view all the options for the `artifacts` keyword here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts